# Umbraco - Error when trying to run 'IIS Express: Start Website' in Visual Studio Code

Tags: iis, visual-studio-code, iis-express, umbraco7

I've just downloaded and installed Umbraco, IIS, and IIS Express (installed the following extension IIS Express in VS Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=warren-buckley.iis-express).

When I run 'IIS Express: Start Website' in the command line in Visual Studio Code I'm getting the following error:

The following site was not found in the configuration file: 'UmbracoCms.7.12.1-d9eb4dfc-b937-4ca5-b37e-a7b3ad857080'

Just wondered if anyone knows what might be causing this?

Comment: Talk to its author, and check existing issues, https://github.com/warrenbuckley/IIS-Express-Code/issues

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

This extension has a hardcoded link to where IIS Express is installed.

Workaround - go to where IIS Express is installed (somewhere in program files), launch it manually and then this VS Code extension will work correctly.